# C++ Tic-Tac-Toe AI not working

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

This is my first time asking question here. Please don't be too mad if I made any kind of mistake here and just let me know what to fix. Thank you a lot :D

I am trying to write a C++ code that you can play a Tic-Tac-Toe against CPU. The CPU must win or at least tie. CPU goes first. As a player, you will be asked to enter 2 numbers, each for row and column.

The problem is that when I execute the program, it stops without any error message at the 3rd cycle of the for loop that starts at line 32. I wonder what I did wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void displayBoard(char []);                   //displays current board
bool isValidInput(char [], int, int, int);    //checks the user input
bool isItAScore(char [], char);               //determines if current player won or not
int getValue(char [], char, int);             //get value of the board by player and number marks

int main()
{
    char tBoard[9], computer = 'X', player = 'O', empty = '.';
    int board[3][3], row = -1, col = -1, temp = 0;
    bool didSomeoneWin = false;

    //initializes the board with numbers 0 to 8
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = temp;
            temp++;
        }
    }


    //initialize the actual board with '.'    
    for(int i= 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        tBoard[i] = empty;
    }

    //starts the game
    for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++)    //it lasts only 9 turns max
    {
        displayBoard(tBoard);

        if(k % 2 == 1)    //player's turn
        {
            cout << "Player, row and column: ";
            cin >> row >> col;    //takes user input range of 1 to 3

            //decreases each value by 1 to work with the array index 0 ~ 2
            row--;
            col--;

            if(isValidInput(tBoard, row, col, board[row][col]))   //iff the input is valid
            {
                tBoard[board[row][col]] = player;    //puts the mark on the position

                if(k > 4 && isItAScore(tBoard, player))    //iff the current player wins
                {
                    displayBoard(tBoard);
                    cout << "Player wins.";
                    k = 8;    //skips to the end of the loop
                    didSomeoneWin = true;    //no tie
                }
            }
            else    //if the input is invalid
            {
                cout << "Invalid row or column number. Try again.\n";
                k--;    //redo the loop with same player
            }
        }
        else    //computer's turn
        {
            cout << "Computer's move\n";

            if(k == 0)    //first move
            {
                tBoard[5] = computer;
            }
            else
            {
                int value = -100, int position = -1;

                for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    if(tBoard[i] == empty)
                    {
                        tBoard[i] = computer;

                        if(isItAScore(tBoard, computer))
                        {
                            displayBoard(tBoard);
                            cout << "Computer wins.";
                            i = 8;
                            k = 8;
                            didSomeoneWin = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int x1 = getValue(tBoard, computer, 1);
                            int x2 = getValue(tBoard, computer, 2);
                            int o1 = getValue(tBoard, player, 1);
                            int o2 = getValue(tBoard, player, 2);

                            if(value < 3 * x2 + x1 - (3 * o2 + o1))
                            {
                                value = 3 * x2 + x1 - (3 * o2 + o1);
                                position = i;
                            }
                        }

                        if(!didSomeoneWin)
                        {
                            tBoard[i] = empty;
                        }
                    }
                }

                tBoard[position] = computer;
            }      
        }
    }

    if(!didSomeoneWin)    //in case of tie
    {
        displayBoard(tBoard);
        cout << "The cat wins";
    }

    return 0;
}

//display the given board
void displayBoard(char brd[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << brd[i] << " ";

        if((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

//checks the input
bool isValidInput(char brd[], int i, int j, int k)
{
    if(((i >= 0 && i <= 2) && (j >= 0 && j <= 2)) && brd[k] == '.')     //number between 0 and 2, and not taken by any players
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

//checks if the given player or computer won or not
bool isItAScore(char brd[], char c)
{
    //chekcs rows
    if((brd[0] == c && brd[1] == c && brd[2] == c) || (brd[3] == c && brd[4] == c && brd[5] == c) || (brd[6] == c && brd[7] == c && brd[8] == c))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //checks columns
        if((brd[0] == c && brd[3] == c && brd[6] == c) || (brd[1] == c && brd[4] == c && brd[7] == c) || (brd[2] == c && brd[5] == c && brd[8] == c))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //checks diagonals
            if((brd[0] == c && brd[4] == c && brd[8] == c) || (brd[2] == c && brd[4] == c && brd[6] == c))
            {
                return true;
            }
            //if none of them fails
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

int getValue(char brd[], char c, int n)
{
    int temp = 0, mark = 0;
    bool eligible = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i + 3)    //check rows
    {
        for(int j = i; j < i + 3; j++)
        {
            if(brd[j] != c)
            {
                j = 10;
                eligible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if(brd[j] == c)
                {
                    temp++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(eligible && temp == n)
        {
            mark++;
        }

        eligible = true;
        temp = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)    //check columes
    {
        for(int j = i; j < i + 7; j + 3)
        {
            if(brd[j] != c)
            {
                j = 10;
                eligible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if(brd[j] == c)
                {
                    temp++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(eligible && temp == n)
        {
            mark++;
        }

        eligible = true;
        temp = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i + 4)    //check '\' diagonal
    {
        if(brd[i] != c)
        {
            i = 10;
            eligible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(brd[i] == c)
            {
                temp++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(eligible && temp == n)
    {
        mark++;
    }

    eligible = true;
    temp = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i < 9; i + 2)    //check '/' diagonal
    {
        if(brd[i] != c)
        {
            i = 10;
            eligible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(brd[i] == c)
            {
                temp++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(eligible && temp == n)
    {
        mark++;
    }

    eligible = true;
    temp = 0;

    return mark;
}
```

I tried to use something called minimax(the formula). I want it to be working properly as intended. It should play against human and make a best result(win or tie, no lose).

It just stops without any error message. The following link is online compiler I am using:

http://cpp.sh/

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: the code has compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a lot of unusual stuff. Your first try with cpp? First in the code is an error:

```
int value = -100, int position = -1;
```

this should be

```
int value = -100;
int position = -1;
```

or

```
int value = -100, position = -1;
```

The first move of the computer set a token to the right of the middle. I think you like to set it to the middle position

```
tBoard[5] = computer;// should be tBorad[4]
```

Next problem, you have an endless loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i + 3) // right would be i+=3
```

The variable i never change, since you only read it, and don't write it. This happens 5 times. A compiler with enabled warnings  would help to find bugs like this.

Next thing, use **break** and **continue** instead of some crazy loop statements. Instead of this,

```
   for(int i = 2; i < 9; i += 2)    //check '/' diagonal
   {
       if(brd[i] != c)
       {
           i = 10;
           eligible = false;
       }
   }
```

use **break**:

```
   for(int i = 2; i < 9; i += 2)    //check '/' diagonal
   {
       if(brd[i] != c)
       {
           eligible = false;
           break;
       }
   }
```

After all this error are away, the program seems to work properly. I think you should use a real compiler, like gcc. With gcc you can use flags to see warnings.

Comment: Answering low-quality questions like this one is not a good use of your time. Such questions tend to get downvoted and closed, and will eventually get deleted, along with any rep you may have received.